# Kibana empty table issue

Tags: elasticsearch, panel, kibana

I am new to elasticsearch and I am trying to follow some basic examples on official webpages. I created a simple index with following mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping' -d '
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "user" : {"type" : "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
        }
    }
}'
```

and then I put some data like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    user: "avoidness",
    message : "hey elasticsearch!"
}'
```

In Kibana when I search for data which I put into index it seems that everythings works fine - except table panel. It always shows an empty table with '0 to 0 of 0 available for paging', even if all other panels are correctly displaying search results. I am using ES v1.0.0 and Kibana v3.0.0 milestone 5.

There is also an inspect frame on table panel with curl query, so I tried to run it from terminal and it seems to works fine, this is what it returned:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "twitter",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
        user: "avoidness",
        message : "hey hou"
      },
      "sort" : [ "2" ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "twitter",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : null, "_source" : {
        user: "avoidness",
        message : "hey elasticsearch!"
      },
      "sort" : [ "1" ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Do you have any ideas why I am still getting an empty table, please?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Your input document is not valid JSON: it misses the double quotes around keynames. Fix it and it will work.

The elasticsearch JSON parser is flexible and can parse invalid JSON, hence producing a valid index. Most kibana components only use data from the index, and work correctly. The table component however requests the document source: since it is stored verbatim, the data returned by the table query is contaminated by it and the browser refuses to parse the resulting invalid JSON.

This issue is also addressed in https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1088#issuecomment-49405144.